# Complex formatting of page numbers (postnote) in biblatex citations

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to change the way that page numbers are displayed in `biblatex` citations to mimic a journal's (moderately) complex style.

The problem is that the formatting changes depending on whether the citation ends with a page range (like a full article or incollection citation) or without (like a book citation).

If the citation ends with a page range the formatting is: space|'at'|space|pagenumber. E.g:

> Malcolm. ‘The Line and the Cave’ [‘Line & Cave’], *Phronesis*, 7 (1962), 38-45 at 38

If the citation doesn't end in a page range the formatting is: comma|space|pagenumber. E.g:

> Irwin, *Plato's Ethics* (Oxford: Oxford University Press, 1995), 38

This much I can do using `\DeclareFieldFormat` to format article citations and book citations separately. BUT since the style uses shorthands for all but the first citation of an article, articles should only use the 'at' for the first citation. E.g, the second citations should be like this:

> Line & Cave, 38

So what I'm trying to do is format the page reference of an article citation differently depending on whether it is the first and full citation or a subsequent and shorthand citation.

Here's a minimal working example (although I've just used the standard verbose style for simplicity):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Malcolm1962,
  author = {John Malcolm},
  title = {The Line and the Cave},
  year = {1962},
  volume = {7},
  pages = {38-45},
  shorthand = {Line \& Cave},
  journal = {Phronesis}
}

@BOOK{Irwin1995,
  author = {Terence Irwin},
  title = {Plato's Ethics},
  year = {1995},
  publisher = {Oxford University Press},
  address = {Oxford},
  shorthand= {Ethics}
}
\end{filecontents}    

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1} 
\renewcommand{\postnotedelim}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, incollection]{postnote}{ at #1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, incollection]{multipostnote}{ at #1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{postnote}{, #1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{multipostnote}{, #1}

\begin{document} 
\cite[38]{Malcolm1962}

\cite[101]{Irwin1995}

\cite[40-42]{Malcolm1962}%Produces 'at 40-42' when it should produce ', 40-42'
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the standard verbose styles this feature is already implemented by the `citepages` option setting:

```
\usepackage[style=verbose,citepages=separate]{biblatex}
```

Under `citepages=separate` the `pages` or `pagetotal` fields and `postnote` are separated by `\postnotedelim` and the bibliography string `thiscite` whenever the `postnote` is identified as a page reference via the `\iffieldpages` test.

Adding the following to your preamble should give you the desired result.

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  thiscite = {at}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:postnote:pages}{%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \bibstring{thiscite}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{postnote}}
```

Under other styles you can obtain the same effect by tracking when the `pages` field is cited and modifying the `postnote` bibliography macro. Here's an example that you can also add to your preamble or biblatex configuration file.

```
\renewbibmacro*{postnote}{%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}
    {}
    {\ifboolexpr{
       test {\iftoggle{cbx:citepages}}
       and
       test {\iffieldpages{postnote}}
     }
       {\setunit{\addspace}%
        \bibstring{thiscite}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}
       {\setunit{\postnotedelim}}%
     \printfield{postnote}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{%
  #1%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifcitation} and not test {\ifblank{#1}} }
    {\global\toggletrue{cbx:citepages}}
    {}}

\newtoggle{cbx:citepages}
\AtEveryCitekey{\global\togglefalse{cbx:citepages}}
```

The `citepages` option also deals with the `pagetotal` field. You can extend the code to this field by similarly modifying the `pagetotal` formatting directive. Note that I've ignored entrytypes and just dealt with the case where the `pages` field is defined. You could of course consider types using the `\ifentrytype` test.

Comment: That's it! Required a little fiddling for the style I'm using, but works perfectly.

Comment: @D.S. Not quite perfectly; I just noticed a bug. I'll fix it in a minute.